# Convert a 3D array to a list of lists

Tags: arrays, r, list

I have a 3D array, for example:

```
arr <- array(dim = c(10, 4, 3), data = rep(rnorm(10), 120))
dimnames(arr) <- list(itr = NULL, chain = c("c1","c2","c3","c4"), param = c("alpha","beta","gamma"))
```

and I'd like to convert it to a list where each element is a param element (i.e., this list will have length = 3), and each list element is another list in which each element is a vector of length 10 (itr) that corresponds to the chain element (i.e., this list will have length = 4).

Any efficient apply based function for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you

```
a <- apply(arr, 3, function(x) c(as.data.frame(x)))
```

Then we can look at the attributes of the result a little bit:

```
lapply(a, names)
# $alpha
# [1] "c1" "c2" "c3" "c4"
#
# $beta
# [1] "c1" "c2" "c3" "c4"
#
# $gamma
# [1] "c1" "c2" "c3" "c4"
unique(rapply(a, length))
# [1] 10
```

Comment: Works for me. I was suspicious the `as.data.frame` might take a while in certain cases, but it doesn't seem to really matter.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering that too, but it preserves all of the names nicely